# Why does the Earth's magnetic field have an angle of 11.5°?

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, geophysics, geomagnetism

Does anybody know why the magnetic field of the Earth have an angle of 11.5°? According to a theory by Prof. Blackett, Earth has magnetism due to the rotation of the the Earth about its own axis. (According to Prof. Blackett, "Every particle is made up of charged particles (protons and electrons). Hence, a substance rotating about an axis will magnetised."). According to this theory, Earth's magnetism should be at an angle of 23.5° (the Earth's angle of rotation), not 11.5°.

Comment: Blackett’s theory was wrong, as he himself eventually accepted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackett_effect

Comment: Also, if a theory/hypothesis predicts one thing (23.5 deg), but the observation shows that the value is significantly different (11.5 deg), then something about the theory is wrong - could be the assumptions made, the proposed mechanism, the way the conclusion is reached, something else, or all of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The assertion "a substance composed of protons and electrons rotating about an axis must have a magnetic field" is false.

Earth has a magnetic field caused by thermally powered convection in its conductive liquid metal core. The process which results in the field is somewhat similar to the way that a car's alternator works: a slight current in a rotating conductive material induces a magnetic field, which (with the addition of mechanical work done to continue rotating the conductive material against the restoring force provided by the magnetic field) induces more current, which induces more magnetic field, which (with the addition of mechanical work as before) induces more current, and so on. See [Wiki: Dynamo Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory).

Convection being a chaotic process with only temporary and approximate dynamical equilibria, the direction of magnetic north and the strength of the magnetic field have changed erratically throughout Earth's past. Geologists believe that as recently as about 800 thousand years ago, compasses would have pointed in the general direction of Antarctica. The magnetic north pole is currently moving in the direction of Siberia (from the northeastern part of Canada) at about 30 kilometers per year.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this answer but object slightly to the first sentence. Charges rotating about an axis absolutely do produce a magnetic field and indeed an (approximate) dipole field with the same axis as the axis of rotation. The point is that the flow of charge carriers within the earth and hence the earth's magnetic field cannot be so simply modeled.

Comment: Coming back to this comment, I see what you meant and you're right. If the substance rotating about the axis has no net charge then there will not be a magnetic field.

Comment: Can we not understand by SRT(special theory of relativity)  rotating a charge about axis will have electric field, and we can also say it will have magnetic field correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, but the electric and magnetic field of all the protons and electrons add together to zero for a neutral body like you or the planet.

Comment: Is the rotation of the earth('s core) important to the field? I'm a little confused by the second paragraph because it starts by saying the cause is convection, then uses rotation in the rest of the paragraph. Is there a rotational movement being created by the convection?

Comment: in that anything rising radially will be accelerated in the tangent direction of the earth's rotation. @RyanJensen

Comment: Rotation is not irrelevant, it produces Coriolis effects that influence the convection currents, but is not itself what drives the geodynamo. Mercury rotates at 1/59th the rate of Earth, but has a similar geodynamo and a magnetic field strong enough to form a magnetosphere. Actually, Mercury's magnetic field is better aligned to its spin axis.